# How can I make an sql query that subtracts times from different rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, window-functions

I have the following dataset showing the status of certain tools.

```
id || Toolid || time       || message    || timeToComplete
===========================================================
1  ||   1    || 1578294000 || running    || 153
2  ||   1    || 1578294153 || assistance || null
3  ||   1    || 1578294204 || done       || null
4  ||   1    || 1578294264 || running    || 208
5  ||   1    || 1578294472 || assistance || null
6  ||   1    || 1578294524 || done       || null
7  ||   2    || 1578294584 || running    || 127
8  ||   2    || 1578294711 || assistance || null
9  ||   2    || 1578294772 || done       || null
```

I need this dataset to calculate the response time, but I can't find a query that succesfully substracts the rows of message=done minus message=assistance.

The output needs to look like this:

```
Toolid || time       || timeToComplete || responseTime
================================================
1      || 1578294000 || 153            || 51
1      || 1578294264 || 208            || 52
2      || 1578294584 || 127            || 61
```

Another challenge is that the assistance-message and done-message aren't always exactly 1 apart. They do always arrive in the same order from the tools (running-assistance-done).

Can someone help me with the necessary query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: What if there are two consecutive running messages?

Comment: @GMB two consecutive running messages can only come from different tools, not the same tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation -- but you need a grouping.  You can calculate this by adding up the number of "running" messages for each row:

```
select toolid,
       min(case when message = 'running' then time end) as time,
       min(timeToComplete) as timeToComplete,
       (min(case when message = 'done' then time end) -
        min(case when message = 'assistance' then time end)
       ) as responseTime
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when message = 'running' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by toolid order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by toolid, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use window `min()`s to get the next "assistance" and "done" rows :

```
select tool_id, time, time_to_complete, response_time
from(
    select 
        t.*,
        min(case when message = 'done' then time end) over(
            partition by tool_id 
            order by time 
            rows between 1 following and unbounded following
        ) 
        - min(case when message = 'assistance ' then time end over(
            partition by tool_id 
            order by time 
            rows between 1 following and unbounded following
        ) response_time
        from mytable t
) t
where message = 'running'
```